# Adding a User Control to a Panel control fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my child page inside a master page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="doctoryab_shokri.Default" masterpagefile="~/web.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="my_content" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1">
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_controls" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

And this is the code behind this page:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pnl_controls.Controls.Add(new sections.doctor_holder());
        //sectios is a folder and doctor_holder is the user control
    }
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pnl_controls.Controls.Add(new sections.doctor_holder());
        //sectios is a folder and doctor_holder is the user control
    }
}
```

I try to add this user control to my panel but nothing is loaded.
I cant use LoadControl method because I need to set a property to user control before loading it.

**ADDED:**

This is doctor_holder.cs:

```
public partial class doctor_holder : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

And this is user control html code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="doctor-holder.ascx.cs" Inherits="doctoryab_shokri.sections.doctor_holder" %>
<div class="doc-holder col-md-6">
<div class="doc-img">
    <asp:Image ID="img_doc_avatar" runat="server" Height="64px" Width="64px" ImageUrl="~/img/opt-doc-logo.png" />
</div>
        <div class="doc-info">
            <p class="doc-name">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_name_lname" runat="server" Text="#" CssClass="doc-name"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <p class="doc-pro">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_proff" runat="server" Text="#"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <p class="doc-addr">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_address" runat="server" Text="#"></asp:Label>
            </p>
            <div style="float:left;">
                <p class="nobat-cap">امکان ثبت نوبت</p>
                <p class="nobat-type">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk_type" runat="server" ForeColor="White">#</asp:LinkButton>
                </p>
            </div>
            <br style="clear: both;">
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you include the code for `sections.doctor_holder`?

Comment: You should use Page_Init event to initialize the user control and add it to the pnl_controls..

Comment: @NiranjanKala There is no Page_Init event in my code

Comment: @CodingGorilla Of Course.

Comment: Yes, it exists. First you should know about the page life cycle events so that you can understand which event is better to use for a specific task. just include `protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }` and put your code inside it.

Comment: I think @NiranjanKala is on the right track, `Page_Load` happens too late in the [Page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the controls have already been rendered so adding a new control here doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I did but the result is the same.

Comment: @Dexter: Use Page_Init event to load the control and after that add it to page at any event before PreRender event

Comment: @CodingGorilla would you please upvote my question? someone down voted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly load use controls like that you have use the LoadControl method. 
The LoadControl method reads the file and instantiates it as a control that can be added to the page.
Example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Reference Control="~/Controls/Spinner.ascx" %>    
<script runat="server">
private ASP.Spinner Spinner1

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Spinner1 = (ASP.Spinner)LoadControl("~/Controls/Spinner.ascx");
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Spinner1);
}
</script>
```

Refer the below links:
[How to: Create Instances of ASP.NET User Controls Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4)
[Dynamic Loading of ASP.NET User Controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59781/Dynamic-Loading-of-ASP-NET-User-Controls)

Hope this help..

Comment: Brilliant! This solved my problem. Thank you. Would you please upvote my question? :D

Comment: I mean <%@ Refrence Control="..." %>

Comment: @Dexter: this example uses scripting code in-line in the the page so it is using that way.  Refer the links to understand the complete scenario.